# Infinite sum convergence test

Tags: calculus

Does the sum:  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big{(}\frac{1+3+3^2+3^3+...+3^n}{3^n+3^{n-1}}\Big{)}^n$$

converge? 
I already tried Cauchy's method, but I'm not sure how to solve the limit.

Comment: Please edit your post as it is very confusing. If you are not sure how to type in mathjax, then upload the original question using pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

This sum does not converge. Note
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big{(}\frac{1+3+3^2+...+3^n}{3^{n-1}+3^n}\Big{)}^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big{(}\frac{1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-2}}{3^{n-1}+3^n}+1\Big{)}^n>\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$$
which itself diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Using the root test:

$$L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\underbrace{=}_{\text{geom. prog.}}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}}{3^{n-1}+3^n}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1-\dfrac{1}{3^{n+1}}}{\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{3}}=\frac{9}{8}>1$$ so, the series is divergent.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 3^n instead of 3^n+1?

Comment: No, it is correct. There are $n+1$ terms in the sum.